# Crystalreports .NET show group footer only on first occurance

Tags: crystal-reports

Using C# vs2008 with crystal reports .net

I am displaying data with multiple groups (3 groups in total).
The first group (or if you like the outermost group) i want to show the group footer only for the first time that group is printed and suppress for every time after.

Im sure i need some conditonal check in the group footer section expert, but im not sure what.

Can anyone please help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In section expert, click the conditional suppress button.

enter this in the formula

```
GroupNumber > 1
```

This will display the group only once

Are you able to use `OnFirstRecord = false` instead.  This may or may not work for you - it depends on the structure of the report.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry to say that prevents the group footer for that particular group from displaying at all. It never displays the footer

Comment: Unfortunately that has the same effect as before, prevents the group footer from showing at all. thanks anyway

Comment: @Spooky2010 - You are assigning this formula on the Group Footer in the Section Expert?  Are you to provide any more details about the report structure - a screen shot perhaps?

Comment: Yes thats where im assigning it.
Ok well i admit i dont realy know what group number is supposed to represent, however i just got the idea to drop a "Group Number" special field in the specific footer im trying to conditionaly suppress and it shows the number "6". The second instance of the same footer shows the number "14".
If i test for 6 i can suppress the specific one i want, but i dont know what the numbers exactly represent and if i can infact count on the footer in question always being group number 6 ???
Any clarification appreciated

Comment: GroupNumber returns the current Group Number being printed.  You could also use `PageNumber > 1` so it will only print the on Page One.